# Alignment in inline math

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumerate, inline

I want to enclose a `tabular` environment with a bracket, inside an `enumerate` environment, and be **aligned to top**.

In the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \(\left.\begin{tabular}{l}
      First line\\
      Second line\\
      Third line
    \end{tabular}\right\}\)
    Text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get everything **centred**, and not **aligned to top**:

[image]

If I ask `tabular` to be aligned at top, then still the inline math is not, so the following happens:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \(\left.\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
      First line\\
      Second line\\
      Third line
    \end{tabular}\right\}\)
    Text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to tell the inline math to also align to top?

Comment: why not put the aligned material plus the brace inside the `\parbox`, instead of the following text?

Comment: Forget the parbox at the end (you can just put 'Text', I agree). If you enclose everything in a `\parbox[t]`, it does not align at top for some reason.

Comment: Just removed the last parbox to make the question more understandable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd define a new environment and use `adjustbox` for this. The principle is the same as in Heiko's answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,varwidth,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bracedrows}{m}
  {\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}%
   $\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}}
  {\end{tabular}\right\rbrace
   \begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}#1\end{varwidth}$%
   \end{adjustbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{bracedrows}{Text}
      First line\\
      Second line\\
      Third line
      \end{bracedrows}

\item \begin{bracedrows}{Text in \\ two lines}
      One\\
      Two\\
      Three
      \end{bracedrows}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With `varwidth` you're sure your side text will occupy only the necessary width.

[image]

Comment: Nice one, specially if I need to use it more than once.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz-Caro Defining an environment has other benefits; you can easily change the appearance of your construction in all places by simply redefining the environment. With the proposed syntax, in the document you only type the relevant material and no formatting instruction, which is *A Good Thing*.

Comment: Sure. In my case I only need it once, but I agree with you.

Answer (score 15):

`\raisebox` will do. The height of the contents of `\raisebox` is available as `\height`. The `tabular` environment puts struts with factor `\arraystretch` in the rows. Since the first line of your tabular only contains normal text, the strut is very likely larger (and probably larger than the extend of the curly brace). Then the argument of `\raisbox` can be calculated the following way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \raisebox{%
      \dimexpr
        \arraystretch\dimexpr.7\baselineskip\relax
        -\height
      \relax
    }{%
      \(\left.\begin{tabular}{l}
        First line\\
        Second line\\
        Third line
      \end{tabular}\right\}\)
      \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{Text}%
    }%
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The magic number `0.7` comes from the definition of a strut, from `latex.ltx`:

```
\setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
  \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
  \@depth.3\baselineskip
  \@width\z@
}%
```

A `tabular` adds these struts, multiplied with `\arraystretch` to get a more uniform line spacing.

Thus the source can be simplified without magic number to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \raisebox{%
      \dimexpr
        \arraystretch\ht\strutbox
        -\height
      \relax
    }{%
      \(\left.\begin{tabular}{l}
        First line\\
        Second line\\
        Third line
      \end{tabular}\right\}\)
      \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{Text}%
    }%
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here `\arraystretch\ht\strutbox` is the height of the first row and `\height` the actual height of the `tabular`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! It works really great.

Comment: I suggest putting a `\relax` after `\dimexpr.7\baselineskip-\height`. :-)

Comment: @azetina: One `\relax` is missing after `\baselineskip`, and `\dimexpr`...`\relax` is missing for the subtraction of `\height`. It matters if `\arraystretch` is not `1`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Where does that magic number `0.7` come from? Can you explain the calculation in detail?

Comment: @ArneL. I have added some explanation and a version without this magic number.

Comment: This works nicely as a macro: `\newcommand{\drop}[1]{%
  \raisebox{%
    \dimexpr
    \arraystretch\dimexpr.7\baselineskip\relax
    -\height
    \relax
  }{#1}%
}`

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
   \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
        First line & \rdelim{\}}{3}{2.5cm}[Text]\\
        Second line\\
        Third line
      \end{tabular}
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This solution made two changes to your latter attempt:

1) It replaced the `\left.  \right\}` syntax with the `\scaleleftright{.}{}{\}}` syntax of the `scalerel` package (with a maximum width on the scaled brace of `1.5ex`); and

2) To lower the `\parbox` the proper number of lines, it enclosed it in a `\Longunderstack` from the `stackengine` package, with the appropriate number of leading `\\` marks to skip lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{.}{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
      First line\\
      Second line\\
      Third line
    \end{tabular}}{\}}
    \Longunderstack{\\ \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{Text}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: If you prefer the centered `\parbox` that egreg introduced, then this also works by changing the `\parbox` from `[t]` to `[c]`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{.}{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
      First line\\
      Second line\\
      Third line
    \end{tabular}}{\}}
    \Longunderstack{\\ \parbox[c]{0.5\linewidth}{Text \\in two lines}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try using TikZ

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (X) {
                \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
                    First line\\
                    Second line\\
                    Third line
                \end{tabular}
            };
            \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] (X.north east) -- node[right=0.3em] {Text} (X.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \large
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (X) {
                \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
                    First line\\
                    Second line\\
                    Third line
                \end{tabular}
            };
            \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] (X.north east) -- node[right=0.3em] {Text} (X.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \Large
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (X) {
                \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
                    First line\\
                    Second line\\
                    Third line
                \end{tabular}
            };
            \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] (X.north east) -- node[right=0.3em] {Text} (X.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \LARGE
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (X) {
                \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
                    First line\\
                    Second line\\
                    Third line
                \end{tabular}
            };
            \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] (X.north east) -- node[right=0.3em] {Text} (X.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Nice solution. I prefer the \raisebox solution just because it's simpler (without loading another package).