# Aligning inline math to top of line, with text around it

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, inline

I am trying to align inline math to the top of a line of text. Currently I have the following:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Solve the system
$\begin{array}{r}
a2-3x_1+5x_2 = 0 \\
1+x_2 = 0 \\
x_3-2x_1 = 0
\end{array}$ in $\textbf{R}^3$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I would like for the top line of the `array` to be at the same vertical level as the text before and after it, instead of centered. I tried just making extra columns in the `array` with the text, but then that doesn't align with the item number of `enumerate` (it just vertically centers the whole thing). Other solutions I've found don't quite solve my problem, for instance [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155793/alignment-in-inline-math) doesn't seem to allow text in the same line after it.

Comment: Beware! It should be `\mathbf{R}`. If you try `\emph{We work in $\textbf{R}^{3}$}`, you'll know why.

Comment: @egreg great point, thank you. Not too long ago I was still using `{\bf R}`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is change `\begin{array}{r}` to `\begin{array}[t]{r}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Solve the system
$\begin{array}[t]{r}
a2-3x_1+5x_2 = 0 \\
1+x_2 = 0 \\
x_3-2x_1 = 0
\end{array}$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stack.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Solve the system
$\Longunderstack[r]{
a2-3x_1+5x_2 = 0 \\
1+x_2 = 0 \\
x_3-2x_1 = 0
}$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need alignment points, you can use a TABstack:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABbinary
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Solve the system
$\tabbedLongunderstack[r]{
2&-3x_1&+5x_2& =& 0 \\
1&&+x_2& =& 0 \\
&-2x_1&& + x_3 =& 0
}$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]